# AWS - Boto -Service Stopping after first service

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

It stops in the first out of 3 services:

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the AddJobFlowSteps operation: A job flow that is shutting down, terminated, or finished may not be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty unclear, but the error message seems pretty clear to me:

`A job flow that is shutting down, terminated, or finished may not be modified.`

You're simply executing an action that throws an error. If your application subsequently stops working, it's probably because you don't have decent error handling in your code, although there's no way to know that for sure, since there is no code in your questin.